# C++: Why I can change the assignment of reference on my computer?

Tags: c++, reference

I am new to C++, and I am studying the concept of reference.

I have studied the fact that a reference should not be assigned to something else once defined and initialized, the description of reference on C++ primer states that once you have bound a reference to an object, then you can't change the object which the reference is bounded to.

I am confused by this statement. I tried the following code on my computer, the compiler didn't report neither warnings nor errors.

```
int a = 2;
int b = 4;
int &ref = a;
cout << "ref = " << ref << endl;
ref = b;
cout << "ref = " << ref << endl;
```

On my computer, the compilation passes, and outputs were printed, one is 2, the other is 4, there's no problem at all.

I am confused by this concept of reference, is it the condition that we **SHOULD NOT** change the object which the reference is bounded to, or we **CANNOT** change the object which the reference is bounded to?

P.S. Even the page 58 on C++ primer also demonstrates the example where the reference refers to new object, and the book says it's ok to do that. Like this:

```
int i = 42;
int *p;
int *&r = p;
r = &i; // isn't this changing r to an new object?
*r = 0;
```

Comment: You did not change what the reference references. `ref = b;` changes the value of `a` via the reference. `a` and `b` now contain the value 4.

Comment: `ref = b` is the same as `a = b`. Look at references as *aliases* of the original variable. After initialization, every time you use `ref` it's the same as using `a`.

Comment: Do `cout << "a = " << a << endl;` to really see what you did

Comment: To see it better, add a few more lines after the code in the question. The first should change the value of `b`; after that, show the values of `a`, `b`, and `ref`.

Comment: Can anyone provide an example of the situation when the reference is changed to bound another object? I am sincerely appreciating any help.

Comment: @MeTAZOIS -- `ref` is a reference to `a`. There is no way to change it to refer to `b`; anything you do to `ref` will be done to `a`.

Comment: @MeTAZOIS `r = &i;` -- The `&` in this case is **not** the reference operator.  It is the `address-of` operator, and it is completely different than a reference, even though it may seem the same.  It is just that C++ uses `&` to mean two different concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> then you can't change the object which the reference is bounded to.
>
> I am confused by this statement

The statement tries to say, that the reference cannot be modified to refer to another object. The object that is referred *can* be modified.

When left hand operand of assignment is a reference, you are indirecting through the reference, and assigning the value of the referred object.

> ```
> ref = b;
> ```

`ref` still refers to the object named by `a`. That object is modified by this assignment. After the assignment, the value of `a` is 4.

> ```
> r = &i; // isn't this changing r to an new object?
> ```

`r` still refers to the object named by `p`. That object is modified by this assignment. After the assignment, `p` points to `i`.

Comment: Is it possible for you to help provide an example about "the reference is modified to refer to another object"? I am still a little confused about this concept, what I understand about this question right now is this: if the object that is referred can be modified, isn't this implying that we modify the object which the reference is referring to?

Comment: @MeTAZOIS Read the first sentence of my answer again: a reference **cannot be modified to refer to another object**. An object that is referred can be modified. You've already shown two examples of the latter in your question. There are no examples of the former because it cannot be done.